# block design and group testing

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

This is a question from course notes:[image]

[image]

The answer I'm given is something like this: 
[image]

So my questions are:

1.How do we know there should be 9 tests? why not 8 tests or 10 tests?

2.How many items are we testing? is it 9 items or 18 items? It doesn't make sense that we are doing 9 tests on 9 items.

Answer (score 1):

The design seems to have 18 blocks and 9 varieties. The standard way to interpret this would be as 9 items and 18 tests.

Of course the dual design would have 9 blocks and 18 varieties. If you read the question carefully, it says "the **items** of the BIBD are the **tests** of the screening experiment". This suggests you want to be working with the dual.

Comment: but why do we need to have 18 tests on just 9 items? We can even test each item, which would only need 9 tests?